# FatalThrowableError in EncryptCookies.php line 59 Laravel

Tags: windows, laravel, cookies, xampp

I hope that you can help me with a problem in Laravel. Is a existing project. I want to know if someone have the same problem.

Fatal error: Call to undefined method App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::decrypt()

```
1. in EncryptCookies.php line 59
2. at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
3. at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
4. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
5. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32 
6. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
7. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide context and if you can the debug messages.

Comment: It is an existing Laravel project that I'm trying to start. At the beginning I had problems with Tokens, but I solved them. Now the problem seems to be with the class that encrypts the cookies.

Comment: Post your routes and groups please.